# Eloquent: How to get all polymorph models?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In this solution from official documentation in Laralvel/Eloquent
([Polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations))

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable_id - integer
    commentable_type - string
```

We can retrive posts or videos:
`$post = App\Post::find(1)` or  `$post = App\Post::all()`

And we can get concrete comment

```
$comment = App\Comment::find(1);
$commentable = $comment->commentable;
```

In this case commentable method will return concrete `Post` or `Video` model.

But how to gel **all comments** as collection, where each of item will be `Post` or `Video` model? `App\Comment::all()` expectedly return records from comments table, this is not what we need.

Comment: I'm not able to test it, but won't the `commentable` function work just like any other relationship method? Have you tried `$commentables = $comment->commentable()->all();`?

Comment: In this case $comment is Post or Video model. These models don't have  ```commentable()``` method.

Answer (score 2):

the official doc also mentions how we should structure our classes

```
class Comment extends Model
{ 
    /** * Get all of the owning commentable models. */ 
    public function commentable()
    { 
        return $this->morphTo(); 
    }
} 

class Post extends Model 
{
    /** * Get all of  post's comments. */ 
    public function comments() 
    { 
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable'); 
    } 
}


class Video extends Model 
{ 
    /** * Get all of the video's comments. */ 
    public function comments() 
    { 
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable'); 
    } 
}
```

After doing so we can get comments of post like

```
$comments = Comments::with('commentable')->get();
```

`$comments` contains all the comments, in each comment you can retrieve `$comment->commentable` which contains either a `Post` or a `Video`.

Comment: Hm.. Yes, but i need get **all** comments in one collection. In this case in collection should be both of models: posts and videos.

Comment: With your comment I modified my answer so you get the union.

Comment: This method does not work as expected. Because, if key is exists in Collection, new element with similar key will not added. Each of added collections (posts, video etc..) have a key from 0 to N. 

I do not think this decision is quite practical. Because, if there will be many related models with unknown names at the time of execution of the program, this will cause difficulty in processing and the presence of redundancy.   Perhaps there are other solutions?

Comment: Please don't use backtick (\`\`) to wrap your string  or it will NOT work.

Comment: This is not `union` but `merge` that you want, I updated the answer as the code was just reinventing array merge